# System.Activator.CreateInstance and threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, activator

I am calling an outside application, which turns an XML into a PDF.

```
dynamic generator = null;
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
Type type = a.GetType("Application.ConsoleStartup.Program");
generator = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

and then

```
generator.Run("testXML.xml");
```

And in general the thing works. The only problem is, that at a certain point the newly opened application needs the STA thread. The problem is that I have no access (or very limited) to this newly opened application. Is there a way to bypass this? Note that I am not really an expert in threading.

The error goes like this:

```
error DCP999: [System.InvalidOperationException] The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.get_Current()
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FrameworkServices..ctor()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip..ctor()
   at Application.Parser.Html.Model.Anchor.AfterInsert(IParseContext pc) in C:\work\Common\Main\Source\Parsers\HtmlParser\Model\Anchor.cs:line 31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use: `System.Diagnostics.Process`?

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = file; 
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: I tried it, it is also a way of doing it, but I need some resource from the application too (like output path in order to open this PDF).

Comment: Well, at the end I still used this one, and it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Try using the Arguments Property. The contents of this property will appear int he args-array of the main function of your other process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your `main` method of the application:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...
```

This is probably down to you new thread trying to access UI elements and in general only one thread per application can do this.

Comment: This is already set by the Main. But I don't call directly Main Method but a method Run

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a new application, you're loading an assembly into your own app.  You can change the apartment model of your thread using `Thread.SetApartmentState`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx

Comment: This is the direction I was already going, but I didn't manage yet to find a way to connect the Activator.CreateInstance(type) and the threading